# How to write multiple lines in one file from bash

Tags: bash

This is silly, and I've tried searching for a way to do this, and many sites instruct to do the same thing, but *nothing* works.

```
#!/bin/bash
message_content="$(cat <<-EOF
    A
        B
    C
EOF
)"

echo $message_content > test
```

Expected output of `cat test` :

```
A
B
C
```

Actual output of `cat test` :

```
A B C
```

What's going on?

Comment: Your *unquoted* variable expansion is undergoing **word splitting**. Try `echo "$message_content" > test`

Comment: @steeldriver ah! That worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this not work for you?:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF > test
A
B
C
EOF
```

or you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
message_content="$(cat <<-EOF
    A
        B
    C
EOF
)"

echo "$message_content" > test
```

as the previous comment suggested. e.g. `quote the variable`

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to put the content in a variable instead of directly send it into the file? The file is just a test to see if the output indeed contains multiple lines.