# how to wirte a multiline text including space key to "late-commands" section in cloud-init "user-data" file

Tags: server, system-installation, netplan, cloud-init, user-data

i am trying to write a `user-data` file so i could deploy many ubuntu server at the same time. but now i am stuck at the `late-commands` section. i am trying to add a `netplan` configuration to `01-network-manager-all.yaml` file. it is a `yaml` file so i have to keep the space key and input multiline text. i tried using
`echo "" >> 01-network-manager-all.yaml`
doing this line by line. is there any way to insert multiline text at the same time? thanks!

Comment: This sounds like it would suit a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents). See for example [How to write multiple lines in one file from bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269866/how-to-write-multiple-lines-in-one-file-from-bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An autoinstall like the following snippet will delete the installer generated network config and write a custom network config using `late-commands`.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      rm /target/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
      cat <<EOF > /target/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
      network:
          version: 2
          ethernets:
              zz-all-en:
                  match:
                      name: "en*"
                  dhcp4: true
              zz-all-eth:
                  match:
                      name: "eth*"
                  dhcp4: true
      EOF
```

**see also**

- [How can I run complex piped commands in Autoinstall / Cloud-Init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390768/how-can-i-run-complex-piped-commands-in-autoinstall-cloud-init/1392251#1392251)
- [Server 22.04.1 subiquity autoinstall - system-install command fails after changing NIC name using netplan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427461/server-22-04-1-subiquity-autoinstall-system-install-command-fails-after-changi/1427754#1427754)
- [Automatic network card configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373687/automatic-network-card-configuration/1373794#1373794)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to insert multiline text at the same time?

Yes, plenty ... In **Bash**(*The default login shell in Ubuntu*), a few examples using:

##### [Here Document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)

```
$ cat << 'EOF' > file
Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four
EOF
```

```
$ cat file 
Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four
```

##### [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf)

```
$ printf '%s\n' \
'Line one' \
'  Line two' \
'    Line three' \
'Line four' \
> file
```

```
$ cat file 
Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four
```

or

```
$ printf '%s\n' \
'Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four' \
> file
```

```
$ cat file
Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four
```

##### [`echo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-echo)

```
$ echo -e \
'Line one\n'\
'  Line two\n'\
'    Line three\n'\
'Line four' \
> file
```

```
$ cat file
Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four
```

or

```
$ echo \
'Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four' \
> file
```

```
$ cat file
Line one
  Line two
    Line three
Line four
```