# The difference in network configuration files between USB install and PXE autoinstall

Tags: networking, pxe, subiquity, autoinstall

when i use pxe with autoinstall install ubuntu server 22.04 or 23.04,the network configuration automatically generated like this

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens9f0np0:
      critical: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.19.106.253
  version: 2
```

when use bootable drive install,the network configuration automatically generated like this:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens9f0np0:
      dhcp4: true
    ens9f0np1:
      dhcp4: true
    ens9f0np2:
      dhcp4: true
    ens9f0np3:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

my user-data configuration

```
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  # network:
  #   ethernets:
  #     ens9f0np0:
  #       dhcp4: true
  #     ens9f1np1:
  #       dhcp4: false
  #   version: 2
  source:
    id: ubuntu-server-minimal
    search_drivers: false
```

To ensure compatibility with network cards from different manufacturers, I removed the network card configuration from the user data, allowing it to be generated automatically. However, it seems that the final configuration only includes the activated network card. When using other network cards, it doesn't automatically obtain an IP address. This results in a less universally applicable configuration compared to one generated through USB installation. Is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: Do you just want a generic network config that uses DHCP for all interfaces?  You can use late-commands to delete the generated configuration and install a generic config https://askubuntu.com/a/1479946/376778